# axios doesn't get post request in redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-form

I have this code:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const storeDevices = values => {
    axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/something/store',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        data: values
    });
}

export default storeDevices;
```

The following code is correct because it returns an object with all data from my form

```
const storeDevices = values => {
    console.log(values);
}

export default storeDevices;
```

Interestingly if I try to use `.then` I have an error:

> axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.create(...).then is not a
> function

Code with `.then`

```
axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/something/store',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    data: values
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you've never told `axios` to send a `POST` request. `axios.create` [creates a new instance](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#creating-an-instance) of `axios` with a custom config. This instance have [different methods](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#instance-methods) (like `.get()`, `.post()`, etc.), none of which is `then()`, so that's why you received the error `.then is not a function`. You set the default method to `POST` but you've never sent a request.

I think you wanted to create this new instance because you didn't want to add the base URL and headers every single time. If you want to create a base instance, you can assign the returned value to a new variable:

```js
const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/',
  headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
});
```

And use this instance to post your request:

```js
API.post('store', data)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try to post using this sintax?

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8000/something/store', values, {headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},}
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

Comment: I tryed. It send null but if I only one click in select it send normal data